# Get Total From a certain timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column of timestamps and I like to have a result where I can see

1. the amount of added entries for a certain date (`added_on_this_date`)
2. and the total amount since the beginning (`total_since_beginning`)

My table:

```
added
==========
1392040040
1392050040
1392060040
1392070040
1392080040
1392090040
1392100040
1392110040
1392120040
1392130040
1392140040
1392150040
1392160040
1392170040
1392180040
1392190040
1392200040
```

The result should look like:

```
date       | added_on_this_date | total_since_beginning
=========================================================
2014-02-10 |                  4 |                     4
2014-02-11 |                  9 |                    13
2014-02-12 |                  4 |                    17
```

I'm using this query which gives me the wrong result

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(added, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
  count(*) AS added_on_this_date,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.added <= t.added) AS total_since_beginning 

FROM mytable t WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY date
```

I've created a fiddle for better understanding: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a72a9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mixing timestamps and yyyy-mm-dd dates...

As you group by a yyyy-mm-dd, you're not sure to know which timestamp will be taken.

You could do

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(added, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
  count(*) AS added_on_this_date,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t2 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.added, '%Y-%m-%d') <= FROM_UNIXTIME(t.added, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS total_since_beginning 

FROM mytable t  GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know i can compare output from `FROM_UNIXTIME`!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more efficient to do with variables than with a subquery:

```
select date, added_on_this_date,
       @cumsum := @cumsum + added_on_this_date as total_since_beginning
from (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(added, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
             count(*) AS added_on_this_date
      FROM mytable t
      WHERE 1=1
      GROUP BY date
     ) d cross join
     (select @cumsum := 0) const
order by date;
```

EDIT (in response to comment):

The above query has a significant performance advantage because it aggregates the data once and that is basically all the effort the query needs to do.  Your original formulation with a correlated subquery can be optimized using an appropriate index.  Unfortunately, once the condition in the correlated subquery uses a function on both tables, then MySQL will not be able to take advantage of an index (in general).

Because the query is aggregating by `date` anyway, this should perform much better.

Comment: Does this method has any advantage to the method by @Raphaël Althaus ?